# permissions to manage google drive automatically removed if app removed?

Tags: security, permissions, google-drive

I recently tested an app called "Autosync Google Drive" by Metactrl. When testing it, I had to give it permission to my google drive.

After testing it, I decided to just use a USB cord to sync my files so I deleted the app.

My question is... does the permission to my google drive by Autosync get automatically revoked by Google? How do I see which apps has access and control to my google drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to log into your Google Drive via web browser:

1. Click the Gear icon
2. Select Settings
3. Click Manage Apps
4. Find the app in question, click on it and select Disconnect from Drive